# Removing Eclipse Symbols

Tags: java, eclipse

I have these strange symbols that appeared one day, and I'm not quite sure how I got it nor how to remove it. I don't really know what these are called so I couldn't google the answer. It's the circle/square and the paragraph symbol at the end of each line of code is what I'm referring to. Any help please?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That are visual representations of whitespace characters. The ones you're seeing represent respectively the [carriage return](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000d/index.htm) (`¤`), [line feed](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000a/index.htm) (`¶`) and [tabulation](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0009/index.htm) (`»`). You've apparently *Show whitespace characters* enabled in *Window > Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors*. Just uncheck the box or finetune the configuration by showing/hiding specific whitespace characters and/or by reducing the transparency level.

[image]

Comment: If, on the other hand, you were coding in the Whitespace language, the characters would be indispensable.